# Bootstrap Twitter Modal - Clearing dialog input fields

Tags: modal-dialog

I have created a modal dialog using Bootstrap and I'm having a problem with the Modal dialog box not clearing form input fields after the box is closed or after it's submitted.

HTML

```
    <!-- Password Reset Modal -->
<div id="passwModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4>Forgot Password?</h4>
        <p>Please enter your registered email address below and a new password will be sent to you.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="sent"><!-- Display sent message after password reset -->
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="reset">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="Email">Username</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input class="input-large" type="email" id="Username" name="Username" placeholder="Email Address">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="controls">
                    <button class="btn btn-inverse" id="close" value="CANCEL" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">CLOSE</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit">SEND</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div><!-- end of sent -->
    </div>
</div><!-- end of Password Reset Modal -->
```

JavaScript (Validation & ajax)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
jQuery.validator.addMethod("accept", function (value, element, param) {
    return value.match(new RegExp("." + param + "$")); });
$("#register").validate({
    rules: {
        FirstName: {
            required: true,
            accept: "[a-zA-Z]+"
        },
        LastName: {
            required: true,
            accept: "[a-zA-Z]+"
        },
        Pwd: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8
        },
        CPwd: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8,
            equalTo: "#Pwd"
        },
        Email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        Agree: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        FirstName: {
            required: "First name required.",
            accept: "Letters only please."
        },
        LastName: {
            required: "Last name required.",
            accept: "Letters only please."
        },
        Pwd: {
            required: "Please create a password.",
            minlength: "Password must be at least 8 characters."
        },
        CPwd: {
            required: "Please confirm password.",
            minlength: "Password must be at least 8 characters.",
            equalTo: "Passwords do not match."
        },
        Email: "Email address is not valid.",
        Agree: "Please accept our policy."
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../process.php",
            data: $('form#register').serialize(),
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#thanks").html(msg)
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
      }
    });
  }); // end document.ready
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that your form will be empty when you will reopen the modal, you can do this for every field on your form. It will delete the last value of your field on the hidden state of the modal when this one is closing :

```
$('#passwModal').on('hidden', function () {
      $('#Username').val("");
 });
```

Comment: Hmmm...still not working. Now I'm adding this function at the end of my other scripts, right before the last closing tag  }); // end document.ready?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on how and when you load your modal. When you click on your submit button, the function should be called.

Comment: You're referring to the button that opens the modal window? In this case it's: <p class="muted"><a href="#passwModal" data-toggle="modal">Forgot password?</a></p>

Comment: Here is an example : http://www.bootply.com/69513, just hit Run, enter value in modal field, close it and reopen the modal, the field will be blank.

Comment: Yeah. Totally works. I have another modal dialog on the same page. There might be a conflict even though they're different ID's. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 4):

Just an update to the previous answer for anyone now using the new Bootstrap, currently v3.1.1, that needs this answered!

```
    $('#passwModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
         $('#Username').val('');
     });
```